# How to extract a td value from a jquery populated table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a jquery generated table and on click I want to extract the value from the clicked td. I am able to do this with an html generated table but not a jquery generated one. Help and here is my code:

```
$(function() {
$('#searchpartno').keyup(function() {
    var item = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        "url": "/searchpartno",
        "data": {"partnumber":item},
        "type": "get",
        "dataType": "json",
        "success": function(items) {
            $('#partnumber_tbody').empty();
            var clearHTML = '<tr>' +'<td></td>' +'</tr>';
            var trHTML = '';
            $.each(items, function (i, item) {
                trHTML += '<tr>' +'<td onclick="updatePartNo()" class="cleardata">' + item.name + '</td>' +'</tr>';
            });
            $('#partnumber_tbody').append(clearHTML);
            $('#partnumber_tbody').append(trHTML);
                },
                "error": function() {
                    $('#dailysale_price').val('');
        }
    });
})
})

function updatePartNo() {
    alert ($(this).html());
}
```

on click it says undefined. Help

Comment: Use the `$("#YourTable").on("click", "td", function(){  .... })`

Comment: Greggz, your solution works on the first click only. on the second click and more it alerts more than once for the same td.

Comment: That doesn't sound right, there must be some external behaviour causing that atypical response

Comment: Ya, the number of alerts are based on the td's. in my list are 5 so it alerts 5 times.

Comment: Try `updatePartNo(this)`. Assuming you didn't mess up the scope, it should be correct your code

Comment: Same results. However, I tried console.log and i've noted its multiplying and creating more td's on every click.

Comment: You changed the signature aswell right ? I don't think your problem is in the onclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it says undefined

Because `this` in `function updatePartNo` refers to `window` object, not to `<td>`. To solve this, you have to pass the correct object to the function.

`<td onclick="updatePartNo(this)"` note `(this)`.

Then your `function` will be like

```
function updatePartNo(element) {
    alert ($(element).html());
}
```

BTW, the autocomplete implementation you're building is not very good. You're sending AJAX request on every `keyup`. It creates unnecessary load on your server. There is absolutely no need to receive matches from the server on every `keyup`. Sorry for the offtopic.

Comment: Kosh, your solution works. However, I don't see any relationship between updatePartNo(this) and updatePartNo(element). Can you clarify please? And yes am using keyup because this is a search input. How would you do it?

Comment: `onclick` attribute creates click event handler on the element which calls function updatePartNo with argument `this`. In this context `this` refers to the clicked element. In the function declaration `function updatePartNo(element) { alert ($(element).html()); }` "element" is just a name of the passed argument. Hope it helps.

Comment: @John, regarding the implementation itself, I'd suggest receiving the matches list from the server only when it's necessary. Imagine, you typed 'a' and received a list: 'anna, asia, ban, bass ...' Then you typed 's' -- you don't need to get a new list, you can use the list you've already got. Just hide the elements which don't match. So you'll need a new list only when your input has changed significantly (say you've removed 'a' and 's' has left alone). Try to think this way.

Comment: your implementation is very good. I'll research on this one. Or do you have recommended materials I would read?